# QTableView select single cell

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have a QT5 application with a `QTableView` , i want to create an action with *Go-To Cell* functionality .

The problem i am facing is that according to the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html) Only `selectRow` and `selectColumn` methods are available as public slots .
In addition i have found a [setSelection](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html#setSelection) method which is `[virtual protected]` , and there is a [setSelectionModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html#setSelection) but i cannot wrap my  head around constructing the `QItemSelectionModel` to select a single cell .

This seems a trivial feature , but for some reason it is not part of the QT api .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To select one item use [QItemSelectionModel::​select](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemselectionmodel.html#select)

```
selectionModel()->select( index, QItemSelectionModel::ClearAndSelect );
```

Make sure that selection behavior set for single seleciton

```
setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection);
```